# ¿Cómo puedo migrar los Extended Properties de una base de datos a otra en SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Cómo puedo migrar los Extended Properties de una base de datos a otra en SQL Server?. La BD2 es un espejo de la BD1 pero tiene los Extended Properties vacíos, en cambio la BD1 si los tiene, por eso me interesa migrar o exportar las descripciones de la BD1 a BD2